# Polymer Dart: is @observable's new value inserted into DOM?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Say I have a custom element, who has a `@observable Map model = toObservable({'k': 'v'});` in its dart file, and `<span>{{model['k']}}</span>` in its html file, when I changed `model`, how can I know, without using `MutationObserver` to observe DOM, that the new value is applied to DOM?

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to use toObservable() on your map, otherwise new values will not be inserted.
2. Why do you need to know when new values are updated in the DOM? If you really need it you can listen to the `changes` of the `ObservableMap`.

Comment: If I understood it right, `changes` delivers `ChangeRecord`, which is about the map itself, non of them is about whether or not the change has been applied to DOM. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: That's right. But that's why you have the Future solution or a MutationObserver...

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to `model.changes` but this is also what Polymer does. To execute your code **after** Polymer added the elements to the DOM you can delay your code like

```dart
model.changes.listen((changes) {
  new Future(() => doSomethingAfterDomUpdate());
});
```

This way you give Polymer time to complete its updates.

Comment: If you delay your code using `new Future(() => ...)` then you know Polymer has already updated the DOM. Polymer itself gets notified about the changes the same way but immediately updates the DOM. If you delay your code using `Future(() => ...)` your code will be executed in a later cycle.

Comment: Don't really understand how events are passed and how Future are scheduled, let me read more and confirm later :)